# Setting system clock stops loop

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi

I have written a Python 3 program which is running on a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B. It uses Tkinter and has a non-blocking repeating function using `root.after` which is performing SPI communication. My problem is that setting the system time back even by a minute causes the function to stop repeating. Setting the clock forwards again makes it start working again. I have simplified the problem to the following program:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

def MyLoop():
    print ("Hello")
    root.after(1000, MyLoop)

root = tk.Tk()

root.after(200, MyLoop)             # Start the non-blocking loop.

root.mainloop()                     #Start the GUI loop.
```

If I set the clock back using sudo date --set="YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" it stops printing "Hello". If I set the clock forwards again it starts printing "Hello" again

The problem is not with the Raspberry Pi as I get the same behaviour on Microsoft Windows.

I can usually find a solution to problems by searching on stackoverflow and elsewhere, but this one has me stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you changing the clock?

Answer (score 0):

It stops, because tkinter uses the current time when calling `after` to compute an absolute future time. When you set the clock back, you'll have to wait until this future time for your function to run.

For example, if at 12:00 noon your call to `after` runs, the next time the function is called will be 12:00:01. If you set the clock back to 11:00,  you'll have to wait an hour and a second before it runs again.